# Error accessing Heroku Logs from Nitrous.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nitrousio

I am trying to access the log from a small Rails app that I have deployed to Heroku, from Nitrous.io.

When I run 'heroku logs' I get the following:
Unable to connect to api.heroku.com

I am guessing that I don't have something setup correctly, but have no idea what.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've already run `heroku login`, Try adding your Nitrous project's SSH keys to heroku. When you're in the Web IDE in your project, type in the command line:

```
$ heroku keys:add
```

Then try running `heroku logs` again.

Comment: Thanks. The login was the issue.